# Moving Outlook.pst off domain onto local computer

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

My problem computer is part of a domain, I am running Win 7 pro and Office 2010.
Problem is PST file is on the server and the local machine hangs bad to where it takes a reboot to get back up. Runs for 30 min than hangs again.

The problem only occurs with Outlook, I think the connection to the server profile is taking to long sometimes and the computer times out hence the hang.

How do I move the file (pst) back onto the local desktop?

Comment: Copy and paste the file then remove the profile from outlook and add it back from the local file

Comment: You mean how do you copy and paste off a network location?

Answer (score 2):

If you are a part of a domain your network administrator should be the person performing the below steps.  You may not have the proper privileges to make all of the changes.

Outlook pst files can get rather large.  Outlook 2010 pst files support up to 50GB files.  If the file is stored on a network share then you could see performance issues with large pst files.  Being a network administrator myself, I have never found a good reason to keep pst files on a server/share.  Outlook always runs much smoother when accessing files locally.  That said the following can be performed to move the pst file and relink it in Outlook:

**How to identify the name and location of your personal folders file**

1. Start Outlook 2010.
2. Click the File tab in the Ribbon, and then click the Info tab on the
   menu.
3. Click the Account Settings tab.
4. Click Account Settings again.
5. Click Data Files. Note the path and file name of your .pst file. For example, C:\Exchange\Mailbox.pst indicates a .pst file that is named Mailbox.pst and is located in the Exchange folder on your drive C.  Click Close, click OK, and then click Exit and Log Off on the File menu to quit Outlook.

**How to copy your personal folders file**

6. On the Start menu, point to Programs, and then click Windows
   Explorer.
7. Browse through the files to the location of your .pst file.
8. Copy your .pst file to the location that you want.

**How to point Outlook to your new personal folders file**

9. Open Outlook 2010.
10. Click the File tab on the Ribbon, and then click the Info tab on
     the menu.
11. Click the Accounts Settings tab, and then click Account Settings
     again.
12. On the Data Files tab, click Add.
13. Under Save as type, select Outlook Data File (*.pst).
14. Find the new location for your .pst file, and then click OK.
15. Select the .pst file, and then click Set as Default.
16. If this is your default e-mail delivery location, you will receive
     the following message: You have changed the default deliver
     location for your e-mail. This will change the location of your
     Inbox, Calendar, and other folders. These changes will take effect
     the next time you start Outlook. Click OK.
17. Click the .pst file that was identified in step 4 in the "How to
     Identify the Name and Location of Your Personal Folder File"
     section, and then click Remove to remove the local .pst file from
     your profile.
18. Click Yes, click Close, and then click OK to close all dialog
     boxes.
19. On the File menu, click Exit.
20. Restart Outlook.

Your profile now points to your .pst file in the new location. Outlook opens your new .pst file, and you can now delete the .pst file from its old location.